# Procedure to separate branch of data in to few set by using for loops in C#

Tags: c#, for-loop

First of all, i stored 90 data in a list.

After that I want to separate those data to 30 data each set, which means that I have 3 set of data that consist 30 data each.

By using the code below, I get what I want but i don't really understand how's it works.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
         for (int j = 0 + (i * 30); j < 30 + (i * 30); j++)  
         {

         }

    }
```

For what I understand is the first loop split the data in to 3 set and the second loops is for 30 data for each set.

Let's say if i have 1000 data now and i want to make it to 100 data each set , so i have 10 set data in total.

So,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       {
             for (int j = 0 + (i * 100); j < 100 + (i * 100); j++)  
             {

             }  
        }
```

Why do `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` / `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)` come first instead of the second loops?

Is it that every time if I want to separate a brunch of data to a few set, the first loops 
that i have to declare is how many set i want to data to be???

Comment: Stepping through code and watching it work is one of the best ways to learn how it works. Asking the Internet (or even some subset of it) is one of the worst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it that every time if I want to separate a brunch of data to a few set, the first loops that i have to declare is how many set i want to data to be???

Yes, it's the convenient way to do that,

This may show a more clear idea of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
     // i is the page
         for (int j = 30*(i); j < 30*(i+1); j++)  
         {
            // 30 is the step and j is the offset
         }

    }
```

Sometimes This structure is called [pagination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination)

which the first loop defines the page and second inner loop defines the step and together they calculate the offset

Comment: If there is a nested loops, is it the first loops must always is be the most outer???

Comment: No, it doesn't, you could code whatever way you like, but it's the most convenient way if I understand your concern, if you made the inner loop out side in this example, you are first calculating every first element of all the pages then every second element of all the pages ... etc. I am not saying you can't do that, just not convenient and bug oriented

Answer (score 1):

sometimes, it's better to refactor and have explaining variables ( or functions)

Also, added Console Output to help show what it's doing

```
int sets = 3;
int setSize = 30;
for (int i = 0; i < sets; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Set {i} : ");
    int from = i * setSize;
    for (int j = from; j < from + setSize; j++)
    {
        Console.Write($" {j}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can write your program any way you like, as long as it works.
But remember, others may need to read your code (for example you left the company and others have taken up your post), and you code in a way that only YOU can understand, thats not a well written code.
There are two main criteria:
Readability: How easy is the code to read?
Writeability:How easy is the code to write?
Balancing the two criteria makes a better coding style.
In your case, breaking it into two for loops (first one indicates the number of sets, second one indicates number of entries) makes perfect sense and is easy to understand.